# Set Imageview to show image in sdcard?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-image

I have a image stored in SD card of my phone. I want to show it in a image view. I know the location of the file. On the oncreate of the activity is there a simple way to say something like

```
ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);    
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() "Images/image.jpg";     
img.setsrc = path ;
```

Please let me know if there is any way to do this. Thank you.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathName);
ImageView img;
img.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Comment: I have problem to load bitmap of image size 1.98 MB , camera Picture size 16M Pixels.

Comment: Do we need to call recycle on bitmap if it is constantly being created and set on ImageView ?

Comment: Image is lost when activity ends, anyway to make it permanent, or do I have to write path string to sdcard as text and read from it each time?

Answer (score 23):

I have this snippet that may help:

```
File imageFile = new  File("/sdcard/example/image.jpg"); 
if(imageFile.exists()){
    ImageView imageView= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageviewTest);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile.getAbsolutePath()));
}
```

**:)**