# Android: Displaying .jpg image from sdcard using ImageView

Tags: android, bitmap, android-imageview

I am trying to display a .jpg from my sd card into an imageview in my layout. I dont get any errors, but nothing gets displayed. I would appreciate any help. Thanks

**EDIT:**

```
        layout1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout1Activity);

     String imgFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Apple.jpg";


            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile);


            ImageView myImage = new ImageView(this);
            myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
            layout1.addView(myImage);
```

Comment: You seem to be missing a `"` in your code...

Comment: you wrote getExternalStorageState() instead of getExternalStorageDirectory(), you can copy it from my answer.

Comment: I think you need this <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224710/set-imageview-to-show-image-in-sdcard> i found its useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

do NOT access the SD card directly, try accessing it trough [Environment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29). Like this:

```
String imageDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/apple.jpg";
```

and then you can call `BitmapFactory`:

```
Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageDir);
```

Comment: Tried it. I still dont get the image. I edited my code to the updated version